# Exponential Powers Precision in Python

Tags: python-3.x, precision

I'd like to know why `5*10**-6 == 0.000005` in Python is `false` but `5*10**-3==0.005` is `true`. Is there a more numerically precise way to change the power of a number?

I expected 5*10**-6 == 0.000005 to be true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is a well known problem with floating point numbers called a floating point rounding error. Because some values must be represented as recurring decimals in base 2, which is what floats are stored as, it is necessary to rounds at a certain precision. This is why if you type `5*10**-6` into the python console, it will return to you: `4.9999999999999996e-06`. This is unfortunately the nature of floating point numbers, however if you do want is situation like this to work intuitively, you might want to consider the `decimal` module from the standard library, the docs for which can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html).